# C++ Can't insert into empty vector

Tags: c++, vector, insert

When I try to insert a vector into an empty vector I get a length error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int> v1;
  vector<int> v2 = {1};
  v1.insert(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1.end());

}
```

and

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::_M_range_insert
```

Is this expected behavior? I thought insert would automatically increase the size of the vector if necessary. And it should insert right behind v1.end(), filling up the vector even if it is empty.

Comment: You want: `v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax is:

```
v1.insert(v1.begin(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

or:

```
v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

Comment: the first parameter should be the destination's position